# Table of content is not proper in chm file

Tags: chm, html-help, html-help-workshop

i have chinese help .chm file, before extracting the chm file the table of contents are showing properly in chinese but when i used the keytool or microsoft html workshop to extract the chm file the hhc and hhk file contents showing some symbols not chinese words. I installed chinese language pack also but its not resolving. please help me to resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Help v1.0 was released 1997. It is old and not Unicode enabled. So all project files (.hhp, .hhc, .hhk) and HTML topic files (.htm, .html) all need to be saved as ANSI. If the HTML is encoded as Unicode (UTF-8 or UTF-16 aka UNICODE) non-English chars wont be handed correctly in the HH navigation (TOC, Index, Search). The embedded browser (content area on right of the help viewer) will however display the topic text fine since this is a UNICODE enabled control.

To correctly compile and display say e.g. Japanese Help you will need to find a e.g. Japanese Windows PC, or change the PC Region settings to use Japanese.

Comment: thanks for the reply it works, everytime its not possible to restart the pc for different languages. is any other tool available to fix this issue or any other way to enable the unicode?

Comment: Afaik binary toc and index allow UCS2 titles. Enabling them might also turn those into Chinese.